# Enabling LWGEOM for OGR tools (QGIS 2.8)?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ogr, spatialite

I am doing some scripted operations on a Spatialite DB using OGRINFO, OGR2OGR etc. in the QGIS 2.8 OSGEO4W shell.

Unfortunately, LWGEOM functions such as ST_Split() are unavailable and lwgeom_version() returns NULL.  GEOS functions appear to work fine.

Is there an easy was to make LWGEOM functions available for the OGR tools?

Comment: Can you mention your OS, please?

Comment: I was hoping for a non-OS specific answer but Windows 7 if it helps you.

Comment: Can I ask why you wanted to know the OS?  I assume you have an answer for a particular OS otherwise it's a pointless question to ask.

Comment: I just remember that LWGEOM was exposed to correct invalid geometries https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqJbVh_OqCE but I do not remember that `ST_Split()` was exposed. The OS is important for installation (because LWGEOM is a C extension). More a clue than a definitive answer.

Comment: I managed to perform a split using ST_Boundary, ST_Union and ST_BuildArea but I'll leave the question open.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it can only be answered by the OGR developers, and so is best asked of them direct.

Comment: `ST_MakeValid` is also not available in `ogr2ogr`, I'm using Windows 10

Comment: The OSGeo4W binaries do support ST_MakeValid (version GDAL 2.3.2, released 2018/09/21)